# Sturm Liouville problem - Showing there exists an infinite number of eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

I've got the equation
$\phi''+2\phi'+\lambda \phi=0$ where $0<\phi<\pi$
with boundary conditions $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi'(\pi)+2\phi(\pi)=0$

I've shown its a S-L problem and written the equation in adjoint form, as well as written down the orthogonality property with it's eigenfunctions.
I've been told Eigenvalues > unity can be found by writing $\lambda = 1 +\Omega^2$.

How would I derive an equation satisfied by $\Omega$ as well as using a graph to show theres an infinite number of eigenvalues as well as their associated eigenfunctions?

Comment: These issues are not as elementary as we might hope, but for constant-coefficient equations you know all the functions satisfying the DE in the interior, and then further impose the boundary conditions.

Comment: $\phi''+\phi'+\lambda\phi=0$ is not a Sturm-Liouville problem on $L^2[0,\pi]$ because it is not formally self-adjoint.